# C++ MFC MDI how to change what class view displays based on active document

Tags: c++, mfc, document, mdi

I'm working on an MDI application that has an object browser (CClassView) that has to change what it displays based on what "document" is active.

PS:  None of my searches have worked.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't what I expected, but here's a possible solution:

> http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?473808-MFC-Doc-View-How-to-get-the-active-document-anywhere-in-my-application
>
> Q: How to get the active document anywhere in my application?
>
> A: There are several methods, one is to get first the active frame
>   then call CFrameWnd::GetActiveDocument.  ... In MDI applications, we
>   have to additionally get the active MDI child frame.

```
CDocument* GetMDIActiveDocument()
{
    CDocument* pDoc = NULL;

    CWnd* pWndMain = AfxGetMainWnd();
    ASSERT(pWndMain);
    ASSERT(pWndMain->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(CMDIFrameWnd))); // Not an MDI app.

    CFrameWnd* pFrame = ((CMDIFrameWnd*)pWndMain)->MDIGetActive();
    if(NULL != pFrame)
    {
        pDoc = pFrame->GetActiveDocument(); // get the active document
    }
    return pDoc;
}
```

This sample code might suggest other (perhaps even better) alternatives:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cstcs513%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: There's just one problem.  There is no `CDocument` class in my project that I know of.  I have `CMyApp: CWinAppEx`, `CChildFrame: CMDIChildWndEx` and `CMainFrame: CMDIFrameWndEx`.  Is there something that I'm missing?